# Compare one value to several possible list matches

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm back to haunt your dreams! I'm working on comparing some values in a complex loop. List 1 is a list of questions/answers, List 2 is also a list of questions/answers. I want to compare List 1 to List 2 and have duplicates removed from List 1 before merging it with List 2. My problem is in the current seed data I have the two items in List 1 match against List 2, but only one is removed instead of both.

I've been at this a couple days and my head is ready to explode, so I hope I can find some help!

Here's code for you:

```
//Fetching questions/answers which do not have an attempt
//Get questions, which automatically pull associated answers thanks to the model
List<QuizQuestions> notTriedQuestions = await db.QuizQuestions.Where(x=>x.QuizID == report.QuizHeader.QuizID).ToListAsync();

//Compare to existing attempt data and remove duplicate questions
int i = 0;    
while(i < notTriedQuestions.Count)
    {

    var originalAnswersCount = notTriedQuestions.ElementAt(i).QuizAnswers.Count;

        int j = 0;

        while(j < originalAnswersCount)
        {
            var comparedID = notTriedQuestions.ElementAt(i).QuizAnswers.ElementAt(j).AnswerID;

            if (report.QuizHeader.QuizQuestions.Any(item => item.QuizAnswers.Any(x => x.AnswerID == comparedID)))
            {
                notTriedQuestions.RemoveAt(i);

                //Trip while value and cause break out of loop, otherwise you result in a catch
                j = originalAnswersCount;
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
            }


        }

        i++;
    }

//Add filtered list to master list
foreach (var item in notTriedQuestions)
{
    report.QuizQuestions.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Try List.Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.90).aspx) It is meant for exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: Happy to help. I highly recommend the Set operations that are available as well. There's some really handy stuff there.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx